# ERROR: DB2 SQL Error: SQLCODE=-206, SQLSTATE=42703, SQLERRMC=CON.CONTACT_ID, DRIVER=4.21.29

Tags: db2

while running this query in DB2 i am getting error.could some one please suggest.

DELETE FROM INT_ADD WHERE IN_ADDR_ID IN(SELECT CON.IN_ADDR_ID FROM CONTACT LEFT JOIN USER_CONTACT UC ON UC.CONTACT_ID = CON.CONTACT_ID WHERE UC.USER_ID=12426371);

Answer (score 3):

You forgot to assign a correlation name `CON` to the `CONTACT` table, which is used for a number of columns from this table.